# getting a "[-251] Assertion error !dsize.empty() " while reshaping and resizing the image as per the input of model

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv

Sending live video feed from raspberry pi to the pc for prediction where I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:/workspace/self_driving_car/server/server.py", line 41, in <module>
image = cv2.resize(image, (320, 240)) / 255.
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.2) D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv-3.4.2\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:3687: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !dsize.empty() in function 'cv::hal::resize'
```

I'm trying to convert the image as per the model requirements.

Following was the pre-processing done while training:

```
img = cv2.resize(cv2.imread('../recvd_data/final_data/'+'image1'+'.jpg'), (320, 240))
img = img / 255.
```

Hence, while predicting I need to do the pre-processing again and that's where I encounter this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/workspace/self_driving_car/server/server.py", line 41, in <module>
    image = cv2.resize(image, (320, 240)) / 255.
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.2) D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv-3.4.2\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:3687: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !dsize.empty() in function 'cv::hal::resize'
```

My code (error occurs in `try` block while resizing):

```
from __future__ import division
import io
import socket, struct, collections, cv2, time, os
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import cnn_model as model


MODEL = 'model/model-2-270.ckpt'
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.restore(sess, MODEL)
server_socket = socket.socket()
server_socket.bind(('192.168.0.12', 8000))
server_socket.listen(0)
connection = server_socket.accept()[0].makefile('rb')
time.sleep(2)
client_socket = socket.socket()
client_socket.connect(('192.168.0.5', 8001))
print('client connected with server')

send_connection = client_socket.makefile('wb')

try:
    while True:
         prev_time = time.time()
         image_len = struct.unpack('<L', connection.read(struct.calcsize('<L')))[0]
         image_stream = io.BytesIO()
         image_stream.write(connection.read(image_len))

         image_stream.seek(0)
         image = np.asarray(Image.open(image_stream).convert('L')).reshape(1, 240, 320, 1)

         """error occurs here while resizing"""
         image = cv2.resize(image, (320, 240)) / 255.
         print('resized')


         pred = model.y.eval(feed_dict={model.x: [image], model.keep_prob: 
1.0})[0][0]
         client_socket.send('{0: 2f}'.format(pred).encode())
         print('sent pred--->>>' + str(pred))

         print('prediction took: ' + str(time.time()-prev_time))
```

Comment: Not sure but problem might be in the conversion from PIL image to OpenCV. Try to convert to an np.array first using np.asarray(IMG)

Comment: image = np.asarray(Image.open(image_stream).convert('L')).reshape(1, 240, 320, 1)

Comment: I have done it.